# Hong Kong airport transit hotel

Tags: transit, airports, hotels, hong-kong

I am going to be flying via Hong Kong with ~9 hours layover between the flights. Usually I would leave the airport and explore the city during that time but since both flights are really long and we have a toddler with us(who probably is not going to be very happy) we would like to find a room to crash to have a shower and a nap before the next flight without having to leave the airport. I've been searching for something like that but I can only find actual hotels around the airport. I am looking for something like "Louis' Tavern Transit Hotel" in Bangkok. Is there something similar to that in HK?

Answer (score 1):

[Sleepinginairports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/hongkong.htm) covers the most likely option:

- Regal Airport Hotel - **Connected to Terminal 1 via air-conditioned bridge**. The hotel is a 2 minute walk or 1 min ride via scheduled airport shuttle. Day rooms are available for use from 9am to 9pm.

As well as two others close by (5 min shuttle) - Novotel Citigate and Sky City Marriot.

But from your description, the Regal sounds most likely.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Just want to be sure, to get to this hotel do I have to collect my luggage and pass the passport control section? Ideally I don't want to spend time standing in lines and then going through check-in again. Thanks!

Comment: It's only connected to the Terminal, unfortunately it's still "land-side" and you'll need to pass through control, unless things have changed recently (and I'm happy to be shown to be wrong)

Comment: Your other option is to look at the lounges, and whether you could sleep in those...

Comment: Regal hotel is on landside, a bridge is connected with the arrival level and around 5 mins walk

Comment: Marriot is in the airport island, walking there takes around 15-25 mins and the path is not covered

Comment: Novotel is in tung chung, walking to there is impossible; however, there is a big shopping mall and a big food court, shopping and eating is much cheaper than in airport

Answer (score -1):

[Plaza Premium Lounge](https://www.plaza-network.com/location_detail?airport=Hong%20Kong%20International%20Airport&city=Hong%20Kong) provide bath and bed service in departure floor, but it is quite expensive

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Have to ask the same question, does that room include bed or just this recliner seat? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Eugene S http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g294217-d6607874-Reviews-Plaza_Premium_Lounge_West_Hall-Hong_Kong.html

Comment: @pnuts look at photos